# Analyze the definition of the cartesian product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, definition

I having problem how to interpret the definition of the cartesian product.

> The cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.
>   \begin{align}
> A\times B=\{(a,b): a\in A \text{ and } b\in B\}
> \end{align}

I understand if $A=\{2\}$ and $B=\{5\}$, we have $A\times B=\{(2,5)\}$. No problem.

But suppose $A=\{3,4\}$ and $B=\{7,8\}$, I interpret the definition as 
$$A\times B=\{(3,7),(4,8)\}$$
This is wrong, but what have I misunderstood in the definition? How should I analyze the definition word by word?

I know the correct is $A\times B=\{(3,7),(3,8), (4,7), (4,8)\}$. However, I dont' grasp why this is correct based on the definition.

Comment: you can see it like that: $A\times B = \cup_{a\in A} \{(a,b)\mid b \in B\}$

Comment: Realise that sets have no order: $\{ a, b\} = \{b,a\}$, so this is the only thing the definition could mean.

Comment: There is a possibility of misunderstanding as you do in the finite case such as this one, or in the case where $A,B$ have the same number elements, but how (with your understanding of the definition) would you deal with $\mathbb{R}\times \{0,1\}$, or even more simply $\{0,1\}\times \{2,3,4\}$ ?

Comment: it's correct based on the definition because it has all the ordered pairs it can have. with one coordinate coming from one set, and the other from the other set.

Answer (score 1):

here's an example of a Cartesian product for you that's more chess related:

$$\begin {array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 8 &(a,8)&(b,8)&(c,8)&(d,8)&(e,8)&(f,8)&(g,8)&(h,8)\\ \hline 7 &(a,7)&(b,7)&(c,7)&(d,7)&(e,7)&(f,7)&(g,7)&(h,7)\\\hline 6 &(a,6)&(b,6)&(c,6)&(d,6)&(e,6)&(f,6)&(g,6)&(h,6)\\\hline 5 &(a,5)&(b,5)&(c,5)&(d,5)&(e,5)&(f,5)&(g,5)&(h,5)\\\hline 4 &(a,4)&(b,4)&(c,4)&(d,4)&(e,4)&(f,4)&(g,4)&(h,4)\\\hline 3 &(a,3)&(b,3)&(c,3)&(d,3)&(e,3)&(f,3)&(g,3)&(h,3)\\\hline 2 &(a,2)&(b,2)&(c,2)&(d,2)&(e,2)&(f,2)&(g,2)&(h,2)\\\hline 1 &(a,1)&(b,1)&(c,1)&(d,1)&(e,1)&(f,1)&(g,1)&(h,1)\\\hline &a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h \end {array}$$

you can now plot relations between the sets on it by coloring it in etc.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of $A\times B$ are all the pairs that have the first element (of the pair) from $A$ and the second element (also of the pair) from $B$.

A typical example: imagine that you have two T-shirts: red and blue, and three trousers: white, green and black. You can dress in six ways:
$$\{\text{red, blue}\}\times\{\text{white, green, black}\}=\\ \{\text{(red, white),
 (red, green), (red, black), (blue,white), (blue, green), (blue, black)}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but it seems to me that this is where you misunderstand the thing:

We have 
$$A\times B=\{(a,b) : a \in A, b \in B \} = \bigcup_{a\in A} \{(a,b): b \in B\}$$
For every element in $A$, we can "attach" any element in $B$ and vice versa.

If $A=\{3,4\}$ and $B =\{7,8\}$, then we have 
$$ A\times B = \{(3,7),(3,8)\} \cup \{(4,7),(4,8)\}=\{(3,7),(3,8),(4,7),(4,8)\}.$$
Now, it is also true that 
$$A\times B=\bigcup_{b\in B} \{(a,b): a \in A\}$$
and we get
$$  A\times B = \{(3,7),(4,7)\} \cup \{(3,8),(4,8)\}=\{(3,7),(3,8),(4,7),(4,8)\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$A=\{3,4\}$

$B=\{7,8\}$

You want to know why $A \times B = \{(3,7),(3,8),(4,7),(4,8)\}$

Look at each element, say $(4,7)$ for example. Is $4 \in A$ and is $7 \in B$?. **Yes!** Hence $(4,7) \in A \times B$. The same goes for the other three ordered pairs.